# Phone Number Conversion and Comparison

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have two columns that I would like to compare: the first column is a residential number that appears in the format of (555) 555-5555, the second column appears in the format of 5555555555.00. I would like to compare the first 6 digits of each number in a third column that displaying TRUE if the first 6 digits match and false if they do not. I have the query done, but converting the columns to be in the same format is killing me. Any help on this?

Comment: You've tagged this with mysql and vb.net. How do you want to do this, in sql or in vb.net?

Comment: I am using a MySQL table and using a datagridview to display the query.

Comment: You might also have a look at the [.Net port of libphonenumber](https://bitbucket.org/pmezard/libphonenumber-csharp/wiki/Home) - which is in c#, but should work just fine from vb.net also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql, a quick solution would be like this:

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  CASE WHEN
    LEFT(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col1, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', ''), ' ', ''),
      6) = LEFT(col2,6)
    THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False'
  END Matches
FROM yourtable
```

Please see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37080/5).